# Traceback error sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column:

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to make a database where there is a prompt for each entry for the INSERT.  However, I keep ending up with the same error of no such column: id

```
        import sqlite3
    
    connection = sqlite3.connect('collection.db')
    c = connection.cursor()
    
    
    c.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entry (
        id INT, 
        acsn INT, 
        did CHAR, 
        g INT, 
        h INT, 
        i INT, 
        n INT, 
        ir INT, 
        at INT )''')
    
    connection.commit()
    
    
    var = int(input())
    
    def entrydata():
    
        id = int(input())
        acsn = var
        did = input()
        g = int(input())
        h = int(input())
        i = int(input())
        n = int(input())
        ir = int(input())
        at = int(input())
    
    
    entrydata()
    
    
    c.execute("""
        INSERT INTO entry(
        id, acsn, did, g, h, i, n, ir, at)
        VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), 
        (id, acsn, did, g, h, i, n, ir, at)""")

connection.commit()
print('Data Entered Successfully')
connection.close()
```

The table is created, however the entry into the table has a traceback error that reads:

```
        c.execute("""
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: id
```

Answer (score 0):

You accidentally put the `"""` after your value, rather than before.

```
c.execute("""
        INSERT INTO entry(id, acsn, did, g, h, i, n, ir, at) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", (id, acsn, did, g, h, i, n, ir, at))
```

But also your variables are defined in the function, they go out of scope after the function is called.